# How can a stored procedure, that is called in C#, correctly insert data without giving all optional parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm trying to insert data with a stored procedure into my SQL Server database, from a C# program using Dapper. When I try to do this, I do not get any error, but some data is unfortunately inserted into the wrong column.

The database consists of a lot of tables and columns, hence the use of a stored procedure to insert data correctly. I have extensively tested the stored procedure in SQL Server itself and know for sure that the data is placed correctly when directly executing SQL code on the server.

Here is the code calling the stored procedure, and a tiny part of the stored procedure script.

```
public void AddIndividual(string genus, string species, string collection)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString: Helper.CnnVal("Rapento.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString")))
    {
        List<Individual> individual = new List<Individual>();
        individual.Add(new Individual { GivenGenusName = genus, GivenSpeciesName = species, GivenCollectionName = collection });
        connection.Execute("dbo.AddIndividual @GivenGenusName, @GivenSpeciesName, @GivenCollectionName", individual);
    }
}


CREATE PROCEDURE AddIndividual
    @GivenGenusName varchar(255) = null,
    @GivenSpeciesName varchar(255) = null,
    @GivenDeterminedBy varchar(255) = null,
    @GivenDeterminationDate varchar(255) = null,
    ....
    @GivenCollectionName varchar(255) = null,
```

In the database, I can see that `GenusName` and `SpeciesName` are inserted correctly, but `CollectionName` is inserted into the column `DeterminedBy`. This is not how it's written in the SQL script. It comes to my attention that `DeterminedBy` is the third parameter in the script, which makes me think that the parameters are not passed on based on the names I give them, but based on their position (the order I in which pass them).

So my question is: How can I insert this parameter in the correct column without having to pass every single optional parameter in the procedure?

I hope I gave you all the info you need. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the @parameter on the calling string and let dapper find the correct parameters to use

Comment: Also, I thought you need to add CommandType.StoredProcedure when calling Execute but if it works....

Comment: @Steve does your comment mean changing this `connection.Execute("dbo.AddIndividual @GivenGenusName, @GivenSpeciesName, @GivenCollectionName", individual);` to this `connection.Execute("dbo.AddIndividual", individual);`?

Comment: Never done it with a collection, you may want to scrap that idea and explicitly set each of your 3 parameters. This way you know for sure which parameter is getting which field.

Comment: @LewsTherin yes. You don't need them and probably are these ones that confuses Dapper

Comment: @Steve Great, thanks for the clarification. You should probably submit that as the answer :)

Comment: @Steve that unfortunately gives an error due to an unnullable value.

Comment: @haag1 I felt that I would make my program better suited against updates in the database. I'm sure I will add columns at some point, and I may very well forget to update some piece of code somewhere. If that happens, the database will be very messy. That is to say, I'm a starter, so you probably know better what trouble I'm getting myself into while trying this :)

Comment: I haven't seen anyone send a `List<>` to a `stored procedure` before. Interesting. I have personally gone `List<> to DataTable to Stored Procedure` and this has worked amazingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing a stored procedure as you are above:

```
connection.Execute("dbo.AddIndividual @GivenGenusName, @GivenSpeciesName, @GivenCollectionName", individual);
```

... what you are doing is supplying a list of **values**, not a list of **parameters**. If you are skipping parameters in the stored procedure, you need to specify the names of the parameters you are filling, like this (*Assumption: The parameter names are the same as your variable names*):

```
connection.Execute("dbo.AddIndividual @GivenGenusName = @GivenGenusName, @GivenSpeciesName = @GivenSpeciesName, @GivenCollectionName = @GivenCollectionName", individual);
```

If you just supply values, they fill in the parameters starting with the first parameter. This is what your query is doing. The primary bit of confusion here is that the values you have set up are handled as variables, **not** parameters.